# Why to transform farm solutions to App Model in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I Know the benefits of being in App Model,
But can some one highlight me of my below concerns mentioned.

1. My whole business logic is available on Js Code when is piece of Cake from Hacker eye.
2. Code Execution is not sure when someone disables javascript in the browser
3. I cannot access appsettings or private assets from web.config by going to App Model
4. Due more .JS files being pulled in HTTP request's too increase and DOM Event will also take more time obviuosly.
5. When CSOM is ultimately hitting the server then how come it'll reduce the load on the server.
6. App part is at the End of the Day is nothing but page loading in iFrame when i'm going for branding it'll completely breaks the relation of master page inheritance.

Highly appreciable who can answer exact answer rather a guess

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the "new" term "add-in" below (instead of "app")

1, 2, 4 All of your concerns regarding Javascript is easily avoided by using a provider hosted add-in, where the logic lives in for example a .Net application in an IIS (just like it does in a farm solution but without it being an integrated part of SharePoint)

3, Still not quite sure what you actual needs are, but with a provider-hosted add-in you can surely save this type of config in for example the `web.config` for the provider hosted part.

5, It won't reduce the load, but it will improve the stability. This since SharePoint can throttle the requests, and if your add-in crashes, eats a lot of resources (like CPU, memory) or throws an error, SharePoint will still be fine, since the app is running in isolation

6, You can use other methods than add-in-parts for more integrated scenarios. For example use Script editor webparts calling a web service that exists in your provider hosted add-in.

Comment: updated point 3 for your reference

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Comment: for 1,2,4 In case i don't have the feasibility of going with provider hosted add-in. let's take scenario where  I've to complete the task using SharePoint hosted Add-in. because for provider hosted add-in all-together I've host the application first on a new server?

Comment: Yes you must, but that could be an Azure web site (that requires no hosting from you). And no I will not take the other scenario, since the question is what you can do about certain limitations and the answer to that is to use the provider-hosted add-in model